# Interlocked operations and alignment with _aligned_malloc

Tags: c, multithreading, winapi

I am concerned about alignment and `Interlocked` operations.  Again.  The documentation for these functions states that the varaible we want to update should be aligned on a 32bit boundary, and that we can achieve this via `_aligned_malloc`.  Fine.

So I have this small test program:

```
struct S
{
    char c;
    long l;
}an_S;

printf("%p, %p", (void*)(&(an_S.c)), (void*)(&(an_S.l)));
```

On release mode, output from this always gives me an address of the long which is 4 bytes after the address of the char, so hence it starts on a 32bit boundary.

1) Is this purely by chance, or can I rely on this hence no need for `_aligned_malloc`?

2) If I have to use `aligned_malloc`, can someone clarify how to do so?  I've read the documentation at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8z34s9c6.aspx but that doesn't seem to show how to assign a value to the memory that is 'allocated'...

3) (Assuming I do need `aligned_malloc`) If I want an array of structures that have a long variable like the above, that needs to be operated on via an Interlocked operation, do I need to add some sort of constructor to set this up or would there be an easier way of doing it?

4) I did a Google search for _aligned_malloc+interlockedCompareExchange and it bought back only 70 results.  That tells me that either the bulk of the code out there that uses `InterlockedCompareExchange` (62,800 results) is wrong or `_aligned_malloc` isn't necessary.  Can someone please clarify?

Comment: you not need any `_aligned_malloc` here. and `long l` will be aligned on 4 bytes, if you not use `#pragma(pack, N)` where `N` less than 4 (2 or 1). and at all, based on your initial question you need absolute else - rundown-protection

Comment: You can rely on this if you use aligned structures. Which is the default. Local variables are also aligned. malloc is fine also. Unless you want unusual alignment like 16 byte.

Comment: Inside of `struct S`, `long l` will be X bytes away from the start of `char c`, where X is the alignment of `struct S`. But, that doesn't guarantee that instances of `struct S`, like `an_s`, are allocated at aligned memory addresses, thus `l` might not always be at an aligned 32-bit boundary. It depends on the alignment used when declaring `struct S`, and the alignment of code that is allocating `struct S`.

Comment: @Remy Lebeau, I'm now confused.  David Heffernan says below that structures are aligned by default.  I'm not saying you are wrong, I'm saying I don't know what is right :\ Furthermore, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment tells me *The type of each member of the structure usually has a default alignment* - so if the first member is aligned all other members will follow aligned after that?

Comment: @Wad that is for *default* alignment. Look at `#pragma pack`, `alignas`, and other similar compiler directives that affect alignment. Think what happens when a structure has alignment < 4, or is contained in another structure whose alignment is < 4. `long l` in `struct S` will not be aligned correctly for interlocked/atomic access.

Comment: Right, ok.  So as long as I stick to default alignment and don't go using any of those directives, I am ok - correct?

Comment: for alignment you ok. for code - no

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your structures are aligned, which is the default, then each member will be aligned suitable for the member type.

As far as `malloc` goes, the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/cpp/build/malloc-alignment) for MSVC explains that on 32 targets the memory is 8 byte aligned, on 64 bit targets it is 16 byte aligned. So you are fine to use `malloc`.

Comment: Right, thanks.  I've discussed this with a colleague who suggests that the reason MSDN stresses that variables must be 32bit aligned is in case someone does something (stupid?) like indexing into an array of chars and casting the result as a long, then using that in the Interlocked function; would you agree?

Comment: Yes, that's one possibility. Another is using packed data structures.